# Date converter on Spring data Neo4j + Kotlin

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm switching from Java to Kotlin for a simple project but I'm figuring one conversion issue. I've on the database :

```
CREATE (:Meeting {on: '2018-10-09', location: "Oracle's offices"})
```

and in kotlin (with SpringBoot + Spring Data neo4J)

```
@NodeEntity
data class Meeting(
    @Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long?,
    @DateString("yyyy-MM-dd") var on: LocalDate?,
    var location: String?,
    @Relationship(value = "ON") var topics: List<Topic> = ArrayList(),
    @Relationship(value = "IN", direction = Relationship.INCOMING) var 
participants: List<Person> = ArrayList(),
    @Relationship(value = "ON") var event: Event?
) : Comparable<Meeting> {
    override fun compareTo(other: Meeting): Int {
        return this.on!!.compareTo(other.on)
    }
}
```

but when I execute a simple meetingRepository.findAll(), I have that exception

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-10-09' could not be parsed at index 4
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorParser.parse(TemporalAccessorParser.java:69) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorParser.parse(TemporalAccessorParser.java:46) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService$ParserConverter.convert(FormattingConversionService.java:200) ~[spring-context-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:191) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.Neo4jOgmEntityInstantiatorAdapter$Neo4jPropertyValueProvider.getParameterValue(Neo4jOgmEntityInstantiatorAdapter.java:89) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.convert.KotlinClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$DefaultingKotlinClassInstantiatorAdapter.extractInvocationArguments(KotlinClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.convert.KotlinClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator$DefaultingKotlinClassInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(KotlinClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:204) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:84) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.conversion.Neo4jOgmEntityInstantiatorAdapter.createInstance(Neo4jOgmEntityInstantiatorAdapter.java:61) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.reflect.EntityFactory.instantiate(EntityFactory.java:126) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.9.jar:3.1.9]
at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.reflect.EntityFactory.newObject(EntityFactory.java:95) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.9.jar:3.1.9]
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapNodes(GraphEntityMapper.java:237) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.9.jar:3.1.9]
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapEntities(GraphEntityMapper.java:212) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.9.jar:3.1.9]
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:138) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.9.jar:3.1.9]
at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:94) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.9.jar:3.1.9]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.lambda$loadAll$0(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:107) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.9.jar:3.1.9]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:574) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.9.jar:3.1.9]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.doInTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:558) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.9.jar:3.1.9]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:94) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.9.jar:3.1.9]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadByTypeDelegate.loadAll(LoadByTypeDelegate.java:118) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.9.jar:3.1.9]
at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.loadAll(Neo4jSession.java:192) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.1.9.jar:3.1.9]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.lambda$invoke$0(SharedSessionCreator.java:108) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.invokeInTransaction(SharedSessionCreator.java:139) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.SharedSessionCreator$SharedSessionInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedSessionCreator.java:110) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy101.loadAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.SimpleNeo4jRepository.findAll(SimpleNeo4jRepository.java:154) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.support.SimpleNeo4jRepository.findAll(SimpleNeo4jRepository.java:149) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.MethodInvocationValidator.invoke(MethodInvocationValidator.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy105.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at be.namuco.dynanetwork.manager.InfoManager.getAllMeetings(InfoManager.kt:80) ~[classes/:na]
at be.namuco.dynanetwork.controller.InfoController.getAllMeetings(InfoController.kt:51) ~[classes/:na]
```

I've then tried with the annotation @Converter with a custom converter like that

```
class LocalDateParser : AttributeConverter<LocalDate, String> {

    val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")


    override fun toGraphProperty(value: LocalDate): String? {
        return formatter.format(value)
    }

    override fun toEntityAttribute(value: String?): LocalDate {
        return LocalDate.parse(value);
    }
}
```

without any success

[image: compile error]

------------------EDIT------------------------

Thx @Xavier

[image]

------------------EDIT------------------------

when I look with the debugger I can see that the parser is looking for a pattern

```
MM/dd/yy
```

Can someone help me ?

config :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-http-driver</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.11</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
     <version>3.1.11</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: What error did you get with the @Converter? Did you use @Converter(LocalDateParser.class)

Comment: yes I tried and he didn't wanted to compile, I even had a Intellij internal error ...

Comment: what kind of compile error did you get?

Comment: I've editied the post

Comment: @XavierBouclet do you have an idea ?

Comment: Try using ::class.java instead of .class

Comment: @XavierBouclet it compiles now but still java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2018-10-09' could not be parsed at index 4

Comment: override fun toEntityAttribute(value: String?): LocalDate {
        return LocalDate.parse(value);
    } Why don't you use your formatter? You use LocalDate. parse without telling it the input format

Comment: @XavierBouclet https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-how-to-convert-string-to-localdate/ it should be fine like that :

Comment: You should do LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);

Comment: Not according to Mkyong

Comment: Ok but could you try it. May be it's a locale pb

Comment: @XavierBouclet same result, I've added a breakpoint inside the converter and he hasn't been triggered

Comment: just curious: what did your code look like in Java (where it probably worked)?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide this problem in form of a small github project?

Comment: Will be complicate because of ownership of the code to a company :/ @second

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add the following [Formatter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/Formatter.html) bean to your project:

```
@Component
class LocalDateFormatter : Formatter<LocalDate> {
    override fun parse(text: String, locale: Locale): LocalDate {
        return LocalDate.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
    }

    override fun print(obj: LocalDate, locale: Locale): String {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.format(obj)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

The above code works if you have `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency in your project. But if you don't - you can add `FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean` to the project and register your Formatter manually (then you can remove `@Component` annotation from it):

```
@Bean
fun formattingConversionServiceFactoryBean(): FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean {
    val factoryBean = FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean()
    factoryBean.setFormatters(setOf(LocalDateFormatter()))
    return factoryBean
}
```

[Working demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-neo4j-demo) in Java.

Comment: I'll try that asap

Comment: Fromatter come from where ? @Cepr0 ?

Comment: because I've no Types arguments expected for class Formatter

Comment: @GillesBodart it's [Spring Formatter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/Formatter.html). Please check the answer - I've updated it...

Comment: I'll try asap and come back